# IIRF: exlude QSA parameter from lowercase on rewrite rule

Tags: lowercase, iirf, qsa

in my config I have:

**Add trailing slash to url and Lowercase**

```
RewriteRule ^/([^.?]+[^.?/])$ /#L$1#E/ [I,R=301]
```

**URL LowerCase**

```
RewriteRule ^/(.*[A-Z].*)$ /#L$1#E [R=301]
```

**rule**

```
RewriteRule ^/category/([^\?\/]+)/((\?.+)|())$ /cat.asp?menu=3&set=$1 [QSA,I,U,L]
```

**now, if I have:**

```
/Category/Test/?gclid=AhdHHSdhjfo34
```

**this is rewrite to:**

```
/category/test/?gclid=ahdhhsdhjfo34
```

**I want QSA parameters is not lowercase:**

```
/category/test/?gclid=AhdHHSdhjfo34
```

How to do it?

Answer (score 0):

**i have found this solution:**

replace

```
  RewriteRule ^/(.*[A-Z].*)$ /#L$1#E [R=301]
```

with

```
  RewriteRule ^/(.*[A-Z].*)\?(.*)$ /#L$1#E [QSA,R=301]
```